# Как вытащить элементы из массива объектов в другой массив

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой массив с объектами

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1, name: "andrey"},
  {id: 2, name: "ivan"},
  {id: 3, name: "nicolay"},
  {id: 4, name: "name"},
]
```

Мне нужно чтоб все id из этого массива перешли в другой уже созданный массив

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1, name: "andrey"},
  {id: 2, name: "ivan"},
  {id: 3, name: "nicolay"},
  {id: 4, name: "name"},
]

let newArray = {
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4}
}
```

Вот так я пытался сделать, но не получилось(

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1, name: "andrey"},
  {id: 2, name: "ivan"},
  {id: 3, name: "nicolay"},
  {id: 4, name: "name"},
]

let newArr = [...array.filter(e => e.id === e.id)]
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так что-ли?

```js
let array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "andrey"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ivan"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "nicolay"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "name"
  },
];

let newArray = array.map(row => row.id);
console.log(newArray );
```

Comment: судя по условию, ему нужно `row => ({id: row.id})`

Comment: Ага, вот так вот)